# Paid Laundry Coin-Free

Tags: api

I am a landloard in Canada and I want to implement a paid washing machine solution without buying a commercial coin laundry. I want to use a regular washing machine that is cheaper, better looking, feature rich, and compact. And I want to add some sort of vending controller.

For the purpose of this question I will assume that the washing machine I will buy has a wire going to the START button that I will be able to disconnect. I will put a relay on this wire.

Ideally, I don't want to program the controller from scratch. Is there an existing cloud service provider that can take care of maintaining the user accounts for me (tenants), collecting payments (PayPal or Canadian credit cards would work), and then controlling the relay remotely. On my side I will have a relay connected to let's say a Raspberry Pi or something like that. That Raspberry Pi will have either an RFID reader or a code keypad to authenticate users. When card is swiped or code is entered, the start button will be unlocked for 15 minutes and the fee will be charged to the API that maintains the payments.

Maybe all this service provider does is just manage balances and collects charges through some API calls from my local interface.

Comment: I sincerely doubt that any cloud service providers are going to offer support for jerry-rigged R-Pi / input hardware, and there are practically none that would handle actual user data for a client. They give you the infrastructure, you handle the data, that's how this works. I'll look through some vendor lists to see if there's anything out there for this, but AFAIK services like TenantCloud and Zora don't offer anything like this. You either need a custom solution or you're going to shell out for a solution. Or you can just go get the coin-op machine. I'll be back if I find anything useful.

Comment: I ended up deciding I don't need to charge for laundry, I can just introduce fair usage policy. (e.g. 2 per day, 3 per week, 10 per month etc.) To do this I will try to build a tag based system, with a relay on the machine's start button (tap the tag to enable the button). I will need some sort of computer with RFID reader, a watch and a bit of storage to store a log of events. I am thinking Arduino but my friends are trying to convince me to go with raspberry pi zero. Thoughts?

Comment: Raspberry pi would be the easier implementation in terms of set up and maintenance. Good policy decision as well, in my opinion at least